# Apply.prototype.push.apply vs forEach for nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, foreach

So I am doing learnRx http://reactive-extensions.github.io/learnrx/ 
and I have a question about making the mergeAll() function (question 10).

Here's my answer, which passes but is not "canonical."

```
Array.prototype.mergeAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        subArray.forEach(function(item){
          results.push(item);
        });
    });
     return results;
};
```

Their Preferred Answer:

```
Array.prototype.mergeAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push.apply(results, subArray);
    });
     return results;
```

};

So ok, if we take a starting array that's [[1,2], [3,4]],  the forEach fires twice, passing [1,2] the first time and [3,4] the second time. Then apply works almost like a forEach here, pushing arguments 0 and 1 which are  1 and 2 into results. Now results is [1,2], then the forEach fires again and arguments 0 and 1 are 3 and 4 and they get pushed. It took me awhile to understand why it works, but it seems confusing, since it's just doing a forEach, right?

Is there a specific reason it's necessary I'm not understanding or is it purely stylistic?

Also, I have a smaller question: why write results.push.apply when Array.prototype.push.apply is more explicit and doesn't require climbing the prototype chain?

Comment: You walk less deeply through the scope chain, you create less function objects, you use the core push function and let it cycles over the inner arrays... There are a lot of reasons indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It took me awhile to understand why it works

…but you did in the end. They are basically equivalent<sup>1</sup>.

> Is there a specific reason it's necessary I'm not understanding or is it purely stylistic?

No specific reason. Stylistically, theirs is obviously shorter (more concise). Performance-wise, `forEach` loops are not very fast because of the many callback function invocations. `apply` is a bit confusing indeed, and not super-efficient either.

However, if they had looked for concise code I wonder why they didn't just use

```
Array.prototype.mergeAll = function() {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this);
};
```

<sub>1: Minor differences for non-arrays, your solution relies on a `.forEach` method while `apply` relies on the `.length`.</sub>